# Any 3d framework for browser that can read in terrain data? WebGL related?

Tags: html, frameworks, 3d, webgl

Any 3d framework for browser that can read in terrain data? WebGL related?

Need to have support for ArcGIS terrain data. The terrain data will be in .3dd format. The end result must be realistic, is able to pan around with mouse and can add real world objects/weather.

Comment: I haven't used ArcGIS before and am not familiar with the .3dd format. On the WebGL related side, I can warmly recommend [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). Is the .3dd format binary or text based ? Any specs ? The 3D framework is there, you just need a parser for your data.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Googling doesn't turn up anything, and that doesn't surprise me. WebGL frameworks are still a young and growing field, and as such support for less common formats is still very spotty. If you can find a tool that will convert ArcGIS to COLLADA or Blender files then you would have plenty of options from there, but otherwise you're probably looking at writing your own loader.

That sounds like a big deal, but it actually shouldn't be terribly difficult as long as the format is well documented. If the .3dd format *isn't* documented, though, you'll probably be stuck waiting for ArcGIS to build their own WebGL library.

Comment: "COLLADA files are an XML representation of a 3D object that can reference additional image files that act as textures draped onto the 3D geometry.", but .3dd file contains terrain data...

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here: Terrain data IS 3D geometry, in a specialized and limited format. COLLADA is also a format for storing 3D geometry, but in a more generalized fashion. As such, it's perfectly possible to represent a terrain with a COLLADA file, it's just not optimized for that specific purpose.